# Why C++17 have two keywords(class and typename) for the same purpose in templates

Tags: c++, class, c++17

> Template template parameter declaration can only use the keyword class
>   and not typename until C++17.

This is the difference between those until C++17.Since C++17, both are same .

Then why not  C++17 deprecating one of the keyword(class) in the template parameter and type parameter declaration?

Because class have two different meaning

Comment: The two keywords aren't used for the same purpose. There are situations where you can use them interchangeably, but there are other situations where you cannot.

Comment: And since when `static` is deprecated?

Comment: Actually, `static` was undeprecated.

Comment: @deviantfan: _"`[C++03: D.2/1]:` The use of the static keyword is deprecated when declaring objects in namespace scope (see 3.3.5)."_ This was reversed in C++11.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But that's not the whole purpose of the keyword...

Comment: The main reason for anything baffling about C++17 is simply that C++17 is a collection of special cases, just like Microsoft software. C++11 was nice improvement. C++14 some ups, but unfortunately also many C++17-like things.

Comment: @deviantfan: It is plainly clear to me that the OP was referring to the specific meaning of `static` that _was_ deprecated. And, if they're weren't, they have now been corrected, so we can move on.

Comment: @SmartManoj: For example, you can use `class` to declare a user-defined type. You cannot do that with `typename`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a subjective question. Personally I would tend to agree that having `class` here *at all* is poor form, and `typename` should have been the only keyword allowed.

But that's just my opinion. Perhaps this usage of `class` will be deprecated in the future; perhaps there are sufficient people who like to write `class` for whatever reason, that it won't be.

At the end of the day, it's hardly the most pressing issue to affect C++, which is probably the real reason that the committee ended up relaxing restrictions rather than adding new ones.

If you feel strongly that this usage of `class` should be deprecated, feel free to propose this to the working group!

By the way, the usage of `static` you refer to was actually undeprecated in C++11.

Comment: @SmartManoj: It means the thing is not deprecated any more.